# Responsive UI for all screen sizes

Tags: react-native

So im trying to figure out how to make a resposive UI for all screen sizes, so i dont need to check every device when i make a new app.

Is there any tip that works 100% ?

Im using "%" for my css elements except fontSizes where i can put only static data for my app about my college but still my app does not seems 100% responsive its like 95% but still some elements have some issues.Im guessing iOS and android has by default some margins,pixel density etc different from each other.

There are many tips like Dimension.get('window') ,flex , % , rem ,pixelRatio and static data .So what of all of that should i use in order to make it 100% responsive? Should i use more than 1 of those tips or my UI will have bugs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you can’t help that’s for sure SO .Thanks for the “tips”.

Answer (score 0):

- For fontSize I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-fontsize. Using that I'm creating a custom Text component that has font size value wrapped with function from this library,
- Use SafeAreaView as the first parent on the screen
- Probably you also want to lock your screen to portrait mode
- If you care about it very much, some UI libraries like NativeBase, tailwind for react native have support for different device sizes. You can customize breakpoints on your own.

In one of the projects, I was using an approach with scaling elements. First function was getting screen's height and width of the currently used device. Then it was calculating the ratio to some predefined values with which designs were created. Then values in stylesheets like fontSize, height, width were multiplied by this ratio.
However, I'm not a fan of this approach now. It required more work and on smaller devices like iphone 7 app wasn't looking good. Now I prefer to scale only font sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is till not getting how i can do it .I mean i have an android phone simulator and a tablet simulator but in tablet the <View> is kind of 1% bigger of all my screens .I was using "%" technique but i still dont know what seems to be the problem.I was using safeAreaView too .No datas are static for my elements .My iphone  simulator too has some issues not big ones but still 1-2% was off.I need to use PixelRatio library or are some default margins on iphone that iOS have?